# How do I evaluate form inside lambda that is within a macro?

Tags: common-lisp

I'm having problems with the following macro:

```
(defmacro gather-params (&rest body)
  "Return plist of params"
  `(concatenate 'list
        (map 'list
             #'(lambda (plist)
                 (if (typep (first plist) 'keyword)
                     (cons 'list plist)
                     plist))
             ',body)))
```

Within the macro, I can't make plist evaluate by adding a comma in front of it, e.g: ,plist when I do that, the compiler complains that the variable ,plist does not exist.

Is there something I'm not understand about the scope within a macro?

Current result:

```
input:  (gather-params (:mykey (+ 1 1)) (list 1 2 3))
result:   ((LIST :MYKEY (+ 1 1)) (LIST 1 2 3))
```

Desired result:

```
input:  (gather-params (:mykey (+ 1 1)) (list 1 2 3))
result:   ((LIST :MYKEY 2) (LIST 1 2 3))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(concatenate 'list '(1 2 3))` is just `(copy-list '(1 2 3))`

-> which both evaluate to `(1 2 3)`.

The macro generates code. It has a backquoted list. This backquoted list is computed at macroexpansion time -> when the macro expansion happens, for example during compilation.

The generated code has a function with a parameter called `plist`. This function executes at runtime. It does not exist during macroexpansion. Thus `plist` is no variable during  macroexpansion. Thus you can't compute a value of `plist` during macroexpansion, since the variable does not exist then.

If you want to evaluate code, then Common Lisp has the function `eval` for that. One can for example call `eval` at runtime.

```
CL-USER 31 > (defmacro gather-params (&rest body)
              "Return plist of params"
              `(map 'list
                    #'(lambda (plist)
                        (if (typep (first plist) 'keyword)
                            (list 'list
                                  (first plist)
                                  (eval (second plist)))
                            plist))
                    ',body))
GATHER-PARAMS

CL-USER 32 > (gather-params (:mykey (+ 1 1)) (list 1 2 3))
((LIST :MYKEY 2) (LIST 1 2 3))
```

Check out this example, with a different approach:

```
CL-USER 42 > (defmacro gather-params (&rest body)
               "Return plist of params"
               `(list ,@(mapcar
                         (lambda (plist)
                           (if (typep (first plist) 'keyword)
                               (list 'list
                                     ''list
                                     (first plist)
                                     (second plist))
                             plist))
                         body)))
GATHER-PARAMS

CL-USER 43 > (let ((foo 1))
               (gather-params (:mykey (+ foo foo)) (list 1 2 3)))
((LIST :MYKEY 2) (1 2 3))
```

Comment: "(concatenate 'list '(1 2 3)) is just (copy-list '(1 2 3))", I know that but how does that help resolve the issue in any way?

Comment: @zimio: it was not clear to me why this is in your example, given that it does nothing useful. For the issue, just read the following paragraphs in my answer.

Comment: With eval I've had more luck than putting the backquote around different places. Although eval still does not produce the desired result. It would be something like: ((LIST :MYKEY (2))) instead of ((LIST :MYKEY 2)).

Comment: it is useful because I want to concatenate the list, not copy it.

Comment: But you don't concatenate anything. There is only one input list. As such it does nothing useful.

Comment: I did not include every possible use case for this function. I will modify the example to include a concatenation.

Comment: You may want to use something like: `(list 'list (first plist) (list (eval (second plist))))`

Comment: That doesn't quite achieve the "desired" result as described in the question. Perhaps you could run it in your REPL and then see if what you get matches the desired result. I think just talking about it without running it against the example given will just lock us into an extended discussion.

Comment: you have now entered more args, but CONCATENATE itself still has only one list arg. The arglist for CONCATENATE is `result-type &rest sequences`. But you pass only one sequence, the result of MAP. Thus this one sequence will not be concatenated with anything.

Comment: Now you changed the desired result, see my example.